# Azure AKS LoadBalancer not properly working

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service, azure-aks

I have a cluster in Azure AKS region East US, with 2 nodes.
i'm using the k8s azure service for the first time, currently i'm free tier subscription.

behind the scene, i have 3 deployment in my architecture, every deployment run single pod, and every pod run single container.

i have 2 deployment to be exposed as external by using LoadBalancer, that make sense because perhaps i need to scale the deployment in the future.

So, when i deploy my app descrption everything works fine, and i exposed the 2 services as LoadBalancer, every service for one of the 2 deployment to be exposed.

but, actually i found that it runs over the public IP for a while then stops working, only one of the IPs stays working and the other not responding.

i searched a lot, and i contact support Azure support team, and he asks me to publish the issue in forum.

i have tried to do some debug, and when i use the port-forward to test the pods, and it's working fine! but the public IP of the LoadBalancer not working.

sometimes when i scale the deployment the Ip works for a while, and i find that when i hit the 2 Ips one of them stops responding..

in our company we need this demo up and running, because in the future we will start building cloud-native and microsevices.

please note that this same app it works fine in other cloud provider using the k8s service.

```
kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
control-expose    LoadBalancer   10.0.141.75    23.96.112.91    8100:31035/TCP   21h
control-service   ClusterIP      10.0.134.81    <none>          8100/TCP         21h
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>          443/TCP          21h
rabbitmq          ClusterIP      10.0.172.174   <none>          5672/TCP         21h
result-expose     LoadBalancer   10.0.218.175   23.96.125.215   8400:30774/TCP   21h
result-service    ClusterIP      10.0.99.114    <none>          8400/TCP         21h

kubectl get endpoints
NAME              ENDPOINTS                                                        AGE
control-expose    10.244.0.14:8100,10.244.0.16:8100,10.244.1.11:8100 + 2 more...   21h
control-service   10.244.0.14:8100,10.244.0.16:8100,10.244.1.11:8100 + 2 more...   21h
kubernetes        172.31.20.10:443                                                 21h
rabbitmq          10.244.0.14:5672,10.244.0.16:5672,10.244.1.11:5672 + 2 more...   21h
result-expose     10.244.0.14:8400,10.244.0.16:8400,10.244.1.11:8400 + 2 more...   21h
result-service    10.244.0.14:8400,10.244.0.16:8400,10.244.1.11:8400 + 2 more...   21h



services: control-expose, result-service
```

please help.

Comment: can you at least show your services\pods yaml? and output from `kubectl get svc, endpoints`

Comment: i have update it

Comment: can you confirm everything works fine if you use internal service endpoints\pod endpoints?

Comment: no, but by using port-forward it works fine

Comment: try enabling insights, also for the master node (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-master-logs), maybe you get some hints there. why are you not using ingress instead of exposing every single service?

Comment: i dont get it, if it doesnt work with internal endpoints problem is not with the load balancer, problem is with the app

Comment: how i can test it with internal endpoints!

Comment: You can provide your yaml file for help.